# Moving logic to a service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've ended up with a lot of logic in my controller which I realise is not good. Therefore I would like to move this to a service.

At the moment the controller accepts a url which will either be from YouTube or Vimeo. It detects whether the string "youtube" or "vimeo" is present in the url and then does what it needs to do accordingly. Here's part of the "logic" that currently resides in the controller:

```
if url.indexOf("youtube") > -1 {
  variable_1 = "Something";
  variable_2 = "Something";
  //do some more stuff
}
else {
  variable_1 = "Something";
  variable_2 = "Something";
  //do some more stuff
}

$scope.task.items.push("I need to add things to this array too");
```

A Service is the way to go but my first question is a `service` or a `factory`?

This is what I'm working on but I'm not sure how I would pass the variables that exist in the controller (variable_1 and variable_2) back to the controller when the service has completed.

```
myApp.service('urlService', function() {
    this.detectProvider = function() {

        if url.indexOf("youtube") > -1 {

        }
        else {

        }

        //how can I push things to the $scope array here?


    };
});
```

Comment: IMO a service and factory are just variations of the same thing. It's a matter of what syntax you want to use. As far as pushing things back, just return something like `return {'var1': variable_1, 'var2': variable_2}`. Then $scope.bla = urlService.var1; - I forget the syntax, but that's the idea.

Comment: Also, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service

```
myApp.service('urlService', function() {
this.detectProvider = function(url) {
    arrayOfMyVars = new Array();
    if url.indexOf("youtube") > -1 {
        arrayOfMyVars.push("Something");
        arrayOfMyVars.push("SomethingElse");
    }
    else {
        arrayOfMyVars.push("Something");
        arrayOfMyVars.push("SomethingElse");
    }

    //how can I push things to the $scope array here?

return arrayOfMyVars;
};
});
```

in your controller

```
var res = urlService.detectProvider(url);
variable_1=res[0];
variable_2=res[1];
$scope.task.items.push('the thing you need to push'); // maybe res[2] and in your service you had another arrayOfMyVars.push('the thing you need to push')...
```

Don't forget to import your service into your controller ;)

Answer (score 1):

> A Service is the way to go but my first question is a service or a
>   factory?

Simply speaking it does not matter. From personal point of view just use what suits you best. A `service` will create a new instance of the function, a `factory` will simply execute the function and do not create a new instance of it.

About your second question: Simply return `variable_1` and `variable_2` in your services method and assign them to your `$scope`.

```
myApp.service('urlService', function() {
    this.detectProvider = function(url) {

        if url.indexOf("youtube") > -1 {
             ...
             return [variable_1, variable_2];
        }
        else {
             ...
             return [variable_1, variable_2];
        } 
    };
});
```

Comment: url need to be pass from the controller to the service )

Answer (score 0):

Service or Factory both are singleton instances. At the end u will get object only.
In service you will create using functtion constructor
In Factory we can construct it using object literrals